# Android thread encapsulation, cannot get changing variables from the encapsulated class

Tags: android, multithreading, encapsulation

I am quite new to Android and Java. Basically, I would like to realize an encapsulation of a background thread of Android, and inside this background thread, I have an infinite loop which will periodically take some operations of getting data(like from Internet, or from some hardware devices).

The encapsulated class must provide only a function like `getData()` for others to get data. But everytime when i call this `getData()` function from other classes, it never gives me the changing values, but only the initialized values.
I've studied both of the `AsyncTask`, `Handler` and `Message` ways to realize multithread. And both of them give me the initialized values.

Here is the encapsulated class of Handler and Message:

```
public class getDataFromUSB{

private int usb_data;

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if(msg.what==1){

            usb_data=msg.arg1;


        }
    }
};

private Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        {
                            int a=read_usb();
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.arg1 = a;
            msg.what = 1;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("");
                this.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
};
public void start(){
    thread.start();

}
public int get_data(){
    return usb_data;
}
public int read_usb()
{ 
    int a=10;
    return a;
}

}
```

And then in another class, here is the code of calling `getDataFromUSB`:

```
getDataFromUSB usb1= new getDataFromUSB();
usb1.start();
int a=usb1.getData();
Log.e(TAG,"a = " +a);
```

Then everytime i call this `usb1.getData()`, the value is always 0. I don't understand why.

Now I proceed to do some more realistic things. I add an object of random in my getDataFrom USB class to provide different numbers, I also change the way of assigning values to usb_data, I think it's better to do it just in the background thread, there is no need to move it to the handlemessage. So it becomes:

```
public class getDataFromUSB{

private int usb_data;
    private Random random = new Random(555L);

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

    }
};

private Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        {
            int a=read_usb();
            usb_data=a;
            Message msg = new Message();
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
public void start(){
    thread.start();

}
public int get_data(){
    return usb_data;
}
public int read_usb()
{ 
    return random.nextInt();
}

}
```

Then I call it from another class like what Nikita suggested:

```
    Handler h = new Handler();   
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int data=usb1.get_data();
            Log.e(TAG,"data= " +data);  
            }
        },500); 
    }
```

The strange thing is that it then gives sometimes all the same numbers, sometimes several some numbers, sometimes all different numbers. As I understand, the usb_data has always been changed inside the background thread, so we are not obliged to wait for handlemessage to proceed. Everytime I call getData(), it should give me the newest value. Isn't that right?

Comment: infinite loop is usually not such a good idea. `periodically` tends to indicate you could use an alarmmanager ?

Comment: define "each time" ? when exactly do you call getData ? just this once ? because in this case, yes, your thread probably hasn't had the time to start doing stuff yet.

Comment: @njzk2, then what would be the good way to continually read from hardware devices?

Comment: you are reading continuously. If you want to display it, for instance, that's probably in the handleMessage

Comment: i know that. my purpose is reading continuously in the background thread and provide data to other classes.

Comment: depends on what you mean by provide. The data is available always, for now it is up to other classes to fetch it. You could add a listener pattern to let other classes register themselves as listeners and send them the new datas

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be following: you run your code from main UI thread. When you new start thread - it sends message to handler. This message is added to main thread's queue and will be processed in main thread when it finishes it's current job. Currently main thread runs your code and there is no chance that message will be processed before you call `usb.getData()`.
To check whether your update thread works properly you can post delayed runnable that will print value of `usb1.getData()`:

```
final getDataFromUSB usb1= new getDataFromUSB();
usb1.start();
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int a=usb1.getData();
        Log.e(TAG,"a = " +a);
    }
}, 500); // Waits 500 milliseconds and runs runnable on current thread.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see where is the problem. And your solution works.

Comment: well. I changed my read_usb() function to give some different random numbers. The purpose is to get the newest value each time when I call the getData(). But when I call it by h.postDelayed() for 3 times, still everytime I got the same value.

Comment: @dengn all messages (and runnables) are added at the same queue. So it really depends on which order they added. It may happen that all runnables are added simultaneously and they run one by one. And after they finished message with new usb_data will be processed. I'm not sure but it's possible.

Comment: But now I assign the values to the usb_data directly inside the background thread, I do nothing in the handlemessage, so now everytime when I call it, it should already be the newest value? it shouldn't have anything to do with the message queue of UI thread any more.

Comment: @dengn hm, right. Weird. Can you add logs to thread to check if it runs between runnables invocations?

Comment: I add a log like Log.e(TAG,"usb = "+usb1.getData()); between runnables, then all of them are giving me the same values. And I think since i have nothing related to the UI operations in my encapsulated class, I don't even need a Handler, right? What I need is only retrieve some data from the encapsulated class which contains a background thread reading data.

Comment: @dengn Yes, you don't need handler now.

Comment: So in that case, when I just call usb1.get_data() without postDelayed i also should get the latest value, but it still gives me 0.